# Stored Procedures & SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm doing some revision in SQL Server and I have a question that I'm trying to work out, I'm meant to be creating a stored procedure that displays all details of branch name, book code, and quantity on hand,the stored procedure takes parameter called `@BranchName`. I'm also meant to use `EXEC` to call this procedure with a value for the parameter.

This is my statement so far (I know that it's wrong and doesn't work some reason, I can't work it out)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BranchDetails
    SELECT 
        B.BookCode, BR.BranchName, I.OnHand
    FROM 
        BOOK, BRANCH, INVENTORY
    WHERE 
        BranchName = 'BookCode'
```

Comment: First of all, tag properly.  It's either SQL Server or MySQL, can't be both.  Secondly, have you read the documentation about how to create Stored Procedure?  That's not even a valid syntax.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

MSSQL Syntax

```
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure_Name, sysname, ProcedureName> 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
    <@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT <@Param1, sysname, @p1>, <@Param2, sysname, @p2>
END
GO
```

to solve your issue.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BranchDetails @BranchCode varchar(20)
as 
BEGIN

SELECT B.BookCode, BR.BranchName, I.OnHand
FROM BOOK, BRANCH, INVENTORY
WHERE BranchCode = @BranchCode

END
```

To execute

```
exec BranchDetails 'Disneyland'
```

Comment: Oh yes, I see your edit, but is there WHERE  correct to be a parameter?

Comment: Yeah it seems to work good, just the WHERE clause i'm using doesn't work because Branchname has to be parameter

Comment: Thank's heaps, would you know how to add a trigger to this scenario to check that the price of a book is not increased more than 10% of the cost of the book? Using only the BOOK table?

Comment: trigger only activates over DML. you will have to create another OP

Comment: and for your reference... avoid using the old style joins. explicitly declare the type of joins